# Como habilitar tecla ENTER no onkeypress de um TButton

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Boa tarde.

sou iniciante com Delphi, e estou fazendo exercícios básicos, dentre eles uma calculadora.

Decidi habilitar o KeyPreview e adicionar um evento, no OnKeyPress para trabalhar com a calculadora diretamente pelo teclado numérico.

Funcionou como esperado, exceto pela tecla Enter, que fica com foco sempre em algum lugar, além de não puxar a função.

Aqui um exemplo da tecla 0 :

```
if key = char ('0') then
begin
  btn00.Click;
end;
```

e aqui a forma que tentei adicionar o evento para pressionar a tecla enter:

```
 if key = char (#13) then
begin
  btnClear.Click;
end;
```

o 13 ali foi a forma que vi pessoas colocando, por ser a key code para o enter, até em alguns exemplos.

Imagino que tenha que antes remover algo do form, mas não consegui até o momento.

Answer (score -1):

Você poder usar esse código:

**No Event do form OnkeyPress**

```
 if key=#13 then
     // sua ação
```

Comment: Ainda sim não funcionou, pois iniciando a execução, o tabOrder foca já no primeiro botão que criei, e o enter "clica" nele

Comment: Coloca seu botão como Default = True;

Comment: E se ainda assim não funcionar  força o foco no OnShow do seu Form

if btn00.CanFocus then
    btn00.SetFocus;

Answer (score -1):

tudo bem, então eu costumo usar no evento on KeyDown assim :

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift:TShiftState);
begin
   { :: ENTER }
   if Key = 13 then
   begin
    //Seu COde....
   end;

OU
   if Key = VK_RETURN then
   begin
    //Seu COde....
   end;
end;
```

Espero ter te ajudado amigo.

Answer (score -2):

Como vc habilitou a propriedade keypress do form. Vá até  evento onkey press do form tenta este código:

if key=#13 then Perform(CM_Dialogkey, VK_TAB,0);

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).